# Field update with attachment ID on Standard Object(Product)

Tags: apex, trigger, app-development

I have a standard object Products where i have a custom text field SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c. I want to store there the image located in attachments(png or jpg) and delete the value in the field if the attachment is deleted.

Here is my code, where I don't know how to add the png/jpg so it can detect only those fieles in the attachments.

```
trigger PopulateIdValueinProduct on Attachment (after insert,after delete) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert())
        ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentid(Trigger.new);
    if(Trigger.isDelete())
        ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentid(Trigger.old);
}
public class ProductAttachment{
    public static updateAttachmentid(List<Attachment> atchList){
        List<Id> parentIdList = new List<Id>();
        for(Attachment att : attList) {
            parentIdList.add(att.Parentid);         
        }
        List<Product2> productList = [select id,SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c,(Select id from Attachments) From Product2 Where id in :parentidList];
        for(Product2 products : productList) {
            String temp = '';
            for(Attachment att : products.Attachments) {
                temp = att.id + ',';
            }
            products.SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c = temp;    
        {
        update productList;

    }
}
```

Additionally i am experiencing this error after i made the change. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ContentType` filter in Query so it will only return images.

```
[select id,SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c,(Select id from Attachments WHERE ContentType LIKE 'image%') From Product2 Where id in :parentidList];
```

Comment: Hi Tushar i made the changes now i am experiencing some errors. Please check the edited version of the question. Thanks

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski you need to define method return type. Also it would be better if you ask new question instead of editing old questions.