# Need help with apex trigger to update/delete attachment id on custom field

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I am trying to create a trigger that will update or delete a specific field in salesforce Products object accordingly. If there is image in the attachment to add the id and delete the id if there is no image. I wrote [another question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210609/field-update-with-attachment-id-on-standard-objectproduct/210610?noredirect=1#comment317494_210610) but I didn't manage to get what I was aiming for so I was told to write it in another question. So here it is. Trying to fix this errors.

I am getting the following errors.
I created a trigger called PopulateIdValueinProduct with the following code.

```
trigger PopulateIdValueinProduct on Attachment (after insert,after delete) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert())
        ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentId(Trigger.new);
    if(Trigger.isDelete())
        ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentId(Trigger.old);
}
```

and an apex class ProductAttachment with the following code.

```
public class ProductAttachment {
    public updateAttachmentId(List<Attachment> attList){
        List<Id> parentIdList = new List<Id>();
        for(Attachment att : attList) {
            parentIdList.add(att.Parentid);         
        }
        List<Product2> productList = [select id,SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c,(Select id from Attachments WHERE ContentType LIKE 'image%') From Product2 Where id in :parentidList];
        for(Product2 products : productList) {
            String temp = '';
            for(Attachment att : products.Attachments) {
                temp = att.id + ',';
            }
            products.SBQQ__ProductPictureID__c = temp;    
        }
        update productList;
    }
}
```

and I am getting this errors.

> ```
> Name                        Line    Problem
> PopulateIdValueInProduct    2       Variable does not exist: Trigger
> PopulateIdValueInProduct    3       Method does not exist or incorrect signature: fogtest.ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentId(List)
> PopulateIdValueInProduct    4       Variable does not exist: Trigger
> PopulateIdValueInProduct    5       Method does not exist or incorrect signature: fogtest.ProductAttachment.updateAttachmentId(List)
> ProductAttachment           2       Invalid constructor name: updateAttachmentId
> ```

Comment: Trigger.isInsert and Trigger.isUpdate. Those are variables, not methods

Comment: I get that @kurunve but what should be the proper syntax for my code? I found this solutions online and made some edits and can't work it around :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't compile because your `isInsert` and `isDelete` checks are properties, not methods.

Instead of:

```
if (trigger.isInsert())
```

Use:

```
if (trigger.isInsert)
```

---

Your class/method don't compile because you don't specify a return type, telling the compiler you want to define a constructor.

Instead of:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public myMethod(/*parameters*/)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Use:

```
public with sharing class MyClass
{
    public void myMethod(/*parameters*/)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

You should always explicitly specify `with sharing` unless you have a good reason not to. Also, in addition to specifying a return type, you likely want to make the method static: `public static void myMethod`.